# When I setup the blockmon, Error:"libblockmoncore.so: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'"

Tags: linux, makefile

```
Linking CXX executable blockmon
libblockmoncore.so: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [blockmon] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/blockmon.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I install the blockmon , after making file,this error comes out.

Comment: With old `libc`-s you need to link `-lrt` for `clock_gettime`

Comment: Thank you very much, I add rt in the linkfile, then it's solved.

Comment: BTW, reading the documentation of [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) would have avoided you to ask the question